# Category of the Debian Jessie (8) to download for the VirtualBox

Tags: debian, virtualbox, system-installation, macintosh

I need to have debian 8 to set up the developer environment for a project and intend to use with VirtualBox in a MacBook Pro machine. I find this page for the Jessie (8) downloads

```
https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/debian-installer/
```

I assume I need to download the `netinst CD image (generally 150-280 MB)` and `amd64`. Can anyone confirm me that? I have next to zero knowledge with the Linux

Comment: You either download the netinst or the full DVD. netinst will need an active connection when installing. The full DVD needs an Internet connection without draconian monthly quotas from the ISP. Have a better look at the Debian pages and browse around a little. There is Debian 9 nowadays.

Comment: I have the `debian9` but its creating issues in the project that I work on